# Shortcode: Image returning null

Tags: php, html, shortcode, visual-composer

I have a block with an image field type:

```
array(
    'type' => 'attach_image',
    'heading' => esc_html__("Image"),
    'param_name' => 'bg_image',
    'value' => __(''),
)
```

To extract the image, I'm doing the following:

```
$getImage = shortcode_atts(
    array(
        'bg_image'  =>  'bg_image',
    ),
    $atts
);

$image_ids = explode(',',$getImage['bg_image']);
foreach($image_ids as $image_id) {
    $images = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id, 'full');
    $image = $images[0];
}
```

And outputting it like so:

```
$output .= "<div class='bgImg' style='background-image:url(". $image .")'></div>";
```

I have set an image to that field type and saved it. However, url is showing up empty and `var_dump($image)` returns `null`. Why is this?

Comment: `print_r($getImage);` to see what you get.

Comment: @Adder `print_r($getImage);` returns : `Array ( [bg_image] => bg_image )
`

Comment: Do you have an attachment image named `bg_image`?

Comment: @Adder - By attachment image, are you referring to the image filename itself? In which case, no, the image isn't called `bg_image`. Only the field name is called `bg_image`

Comment: Is this inside a shortcode? Can you pass a value for bg_image to the shortcode?

Answer (score 0):

check you $var if is equal put correctlly